# Disble hotlinking from specific domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using the following .htaccess code to disable hot linking from one specific domain :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www.)?bad-site.com [NC]
 Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/bad.jpg [r=301,nc]
```

What if I want to disable more domains. How do I do that? Is it possible to do it without duplicating the configuration for every domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a RewriteCond for every domain and use OR like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?bad-site\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?bad-site-1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?bad-site-2\.com [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/bad.jpg [r=307,NC]
```

or you cand use | in the regexp like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?((bad-site\.com)|(bad-site-1\.com)|(bad-site-2\.com)) [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/bad.jpg [r=307,NC]
```

Comment: By the way, the dots, in the RewriteCond, would match any character and should be escaped: www\.bad-site\.com .

Comment: @Gruikya - I was in a hurry and just copied his regexp without checking it (my little son needed me :), and I planed to return to recheck the regexp) ... I update the regexp. Thanks anyway

Comment: The first code did not work. it referee everything to bad.jpg image, I think the last [NC,OR] is not correct, maybe it should be [NC] because no need for OR any more.Can you please look at it? The second works fine without any problem.  Thanks a lot

Comment: I updated first code, the problem was in r=301 after the first rule match&redirect, it will redirect every request even it doesn't match, until I cleared my browser cache, beacause "301 Moved Permanently" is used for permanent redirection, maybe is better suited a "307 Temporary Redirect", removed OR beacause that to can get wrong results.